# how do i count a variable in java with array?

Tags: java, android

When I try to count an array my Android App go Stop.
My code is like this:

```
int counter = 0;
String arr[] = {"value1","value2","value3","value4"};

....

public void next(View v){
    counter = counter + 1;
    if(counter >= 4){
        counter = 0;
    }
    textview.setText(arr[counter]);
}
```

Comment: Arrays  in Java are Zero based. BTW. Look into the logCat and you will see the exception

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine as I tried building and running the code. There must be some other exceptions you're running in. Please have a look at logCat to find other exceptions and errors to get further assistance.